# Wildfly 9 JMS injection not happening

Tags: java, jboss, jms, cdi, wildfly

The following class is deployed in JBoss 9.02-final, but the injected fields are null:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JMSEventPublisher implements IEventPublisherClient {

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource (mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/Events")
    private Queue syncQueue;
```

I've tried using `@Stateless` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`, and I've tried using `lookup` instead of `mappedName`, but the context and syncQueue fields are never injected (so I get null pointer exceptions when I try to send a JMS message).

There's no error message in the JBoss log when the war is started up.  On JBoss startup, here is the JMS-related output, where we can see that the named queue seems to be started without any error message:

```
10:41:59,972 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.7.Final (2.4.7.Final, 12
4) [34da3fdf-8dba-11e5-9213-51bb5b0e6fe5] 
10:42:00,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/ex
ported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
10:42:00,459 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
10:42:00,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/Connect
ionFactory
10:42:00,472 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.Events
10:42:00,476 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
10:42:00,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
10:42:00,633 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-3) HornetQ resource adaptor started
10:42:00,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service 
thread 1-3) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
10:42:00,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
10:42:00,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSC
onnectionFactory
```

Any idea why this injection is not happening?

Comment: How do you retrieve a reference to this class?

Comment: What does you lib folder of deployment look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @John Ament, who asked the right question.  I found that in the my factory class the reference was created by a `new`, so WELD did not do the injection.  Issue resolved.

I removed the `new JMSEventPublisher()` and instead added `@Inject` on the field in the factory class (and BTW, my working version of `JMSEventPublisher` uses `lookup` instead of `mappedName` for the resource lookup for `syncQueue`).